# Top_p parameter in langchain

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sampling, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to understand the `top_p` parameter in langchain (nucleus sampling) but I can't seem to grasp it.
Based on [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/science-control-how-temperature-topp-topk-shape-large-puente-viejo-u88yf/) we sort the probabilities and select a subset that exceeds p and concurrently has the fewer members possible.
For example for:

```
t1 =0.05
t2 = 0.5
t3 = 0.3
t4 = 0.15
```

and `top_p=0.75` we would select `t2` and `t3`, right?

If this is the case what happens if `top_p=0.001`?
We just need one token and any one of these is enough.
Do we select the biggest one (`t2`)? (based on my experience this makes sense, since i tested `top_p=0.001` on an LLM and the output was coherent, so since we select only one token if it was a random token with `probability >0.001` the output should be garbage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `top_p=0.75` we would select `t2` and `t3`, right? → **YES.**

If `top_p=0.001`? → **We would select only `t2`.**

This is the [original definition](https://openreview.net/forum?id=rygGQyrFvH):

> The key idea is to use the shape of the probability distribution to determine the set of tokens to be sampled from. Given a distribution $P(x | x_{1:i-1})$, we define its top-$p$ vocabulary $V^{(p)} \subset V$ as the smallest set such that
> \begin{equation}
>     \sum_{x \in V^{(p)}} P(x | x_{1:i-1}) \geq p.
> \end{equation}

I would add something about the lines "the result of the sum shall be maximal among all possible combinations".

In practical terms, we can take a look at the [original implementation](https://github.com/ari-holtzman/degen/blob/0acfd2d0ba8484e24e9c5241f75f34be15ef2609/gen.py#L127C1-L140C83):

```
sorted_probs, sorted_indices = torch.sort(samp_probs, descending=True)
cumulative_probs = torch.cumsum(sorted_probs, dim=-1)
sorted_indices_to_remove = cumulative_probs > p
sorted_indices_to_remove[:, 1:] = sorted_indices_to_remove[:, :-1].clone()
sorted_indices_to_remove[:, 0] = 0
sorted_samp_probs = sorted_probs.clone()
sorted_samp_probs[sorted_indices_to_remove] = 0

...

sorted_next_indices = sorted_samp_probs.multinomial(1).view(-1, 1)
next_tokens = sorted_indices.gather(1, sorted_next_indices)
next_logprobs = sorted_samp_probs.gather(1, sorted_next_indices).log()
```

There, we can see that the first thing they do is sorting and then they compute the cumulative probability distribution to find the cutting point.